# Error when running compiled typescript project with dynamically imported modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

i'm trying to dynamically import custom modules in my project. for example, i have this project structure;

```
+-modules
| |-modules-1.ts
| |-modules-2.ts
| +-modules-3.ts
|
+-index.ts
```

where in `index.ts` i'm trying to load all files in `modules` like this:

```
import fs from 'fs';

fs.readdirSync(`./modules`).forEach(async (file: string) => {
    const source = await import(`./modules/${file}`);

    // rest of codes ...
});
```

And in `module-1.ts`:

```
import express from `express`;

// rest of the code ...
```

it's all fine when i'm running it using `nodemon index.ts`. but when i compile it using `tsc -p .` and run the `.js` file, i got this error;

```
(node:50543) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: /home/project/Modules/module-1.ts:1
import express from 'express':
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

i've tried using `require()` instead of `import()` but the result is still the same. it worked if i import the modules 1 by 1 like (in `index.ts`);

```
import * as module1 from './modules/module-1.ts';
import * as module2 from './modules/module-2.ts';
import * as module3 from './modules/module-3.ts';

// rest of the code ...
```

but in reality, i may have a lot of custom modules and i wonder if i can just use my method earlier to load all of it. any solution/suggestion would be very appreciated.